# Can't use unebootin or re-install windows

Tags: windows-7, live-usb, unetbootin

I had windows 7 installed before I install ubuntu, I downloaded ubuntu when I had windows and installed it but I removed all my data by accident and I lost my windows 7, now I'm trying to install windows back but I completely fail doing that!

Why do you fail?

Actually I downloaded windows ISO file, I searched online how to install windows using ubuntu and I knew that I have to formate my USB  to NFTS using gparted, I did, everything is fine now I opened UneBootIN but I can't find my USB, can't be detected then error message pop-up saying I have to formate my USB to FAT32, and I know that I can't do that to install windows 7 or boot it, but I gave it try and formatted my USB to FAT32, everything went well and it made the usb boot-able I restarted my device and pressed F2, it showed my USB, I choosed it and pressed enter, it said in the top: UnEbootIN and there's something in the list called 'Default' and message down saying 'Boot or whatever will happen, install or boot after 10 seconds, I wait 10 seconds and it recount again, I press enter and nothing happen just re count the 10 seconds! and I can't find any similar programs like UneBootIN to do that for me so i'm stuck on ubuntu only, I wanna install ubuntu as alternate os when I install windows but I'm just stuck on it now..

I wanna something to make me make windows 7 bootable instead of UneBootin because it doesn't detect NTFS Formatted USB, and I can't go with FAT32 cuz it doesn't work!

Comment: Try Universal USB installer.

Comment: Why don't you try burning the iso to a DVD?

Comment: If I have DVD I wouldn't post here. It's kinda impossible to get it at the moment, but thanks for your feedback. @Raphael

Comment: @kraxor Actually, winboot doesn't seem to work on 14.04.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic What is "winboot" and how is it related to this?

Comment: @kraxor Sorry, I meant winusb

Comment: It always gives me some strange errors after waiting a lot of time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9lpu5n2nvh6ykf9/AACs7VQpp8I6F7ZzlnbmoOOZa) older version of unetbooting which support NTFS partitions. Make sure you mark it as executable before running. The newer versions don't support NTFS. Also, check the "Show all discs" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks very much! It can detect it now! I will try booting and I will comment again.